# How do I replace values with NA given a condition of column location and factors in another column?

Tags: r, dplyr, replace

Im having some issues understanding how to input some NA values in a "complicated" data set. I want to remove the values from columns where the "season" within the season column does not match with the column names. I think there is a way to do this using `grep` and `mutate()` but I'm not sure if that's the right way to go about it.

```
data <- data.frame(season = c("level1", "level1", "level2", "level2"),
level1_01 = c(12, 10, 0, 3),
level1_02 = c(12, 10, 0, 3),
level2_01 = c(12, 10, 0, 3),
level2_02 = c(12, 10, 0, 3),
level3_01 = c(12, 10, 0, 3),
level3_02 = c(12, 10, 0, 3))


> data
> season level1_01 level1_02 level2_01 level2_02 level3_01 level3_02
> 1 level1        12        12        12        12        12        12
> 2 level1        10        10        10        10        10        10
> 3 level2         0         0         0         0         0         0
> 4 level2         3         3         3         3         3         3
```

I want the data frame to look like this.

```
> data
> season level1_01 level1_02 level2_01 level2_02 level3_01 level3_02
> 1 level1        12        12        NA        NA        NA        NA
> 2 level1        10        10        NA        NA        NA        NA
> 3 level2        NA        NA         0         0        NA        NA
> 4 level2        NA        NA         3         3        NA        NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**
Per OP data update: Now we can simply match each row's `season` against column value.  That removes the need for a list-column, the pivoted `mutate` is now just:

```
mutate(value = if_else(str_detect(name, season), value, NA_real_))
```

Full updated code:

```
data |>
  group_by(season) |> 
  mutate(grp_id = row_number()) |> 
  pivot_longer(-c(season, grp_id)) |> 
  mutate(value = if_else(str_detect(name, season), value, NA_real_)) |> 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(grp_id, season), 
              names_from = name, 
              values_from = value) |> 
  select(-grp_id) |> 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 4 × 7
  season level1_01 level1_02 level2_01 level2_02 level3_01 level3_02
  <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 level1        12        12        NA        NA        NA        NA
2 level1        10        10        NA        NA        NA        NA
3 level2        NA        NA         0         0        NA        NA
4 level2        NA        NA         3         3        NA        NA
```

**Original**
You can add a list-column that contains all `seasons` values, then `pivot_longer` to filter column names based on `seasons`. Then pivot back to wide and you're done.

```
library(tidyverse)

data |>
  group_by(season) |> 
  mutate(grp_id = row_number()) |> 
  pivot_longer(-c(season, grp_id)) |> 
  mutate(seasons = list(unique(data$season)),
         value = if_else(
           str_detect(name, map_chr(list(unique(data$season)), 
                                    \(x) paste(x, collapse = "|"))),
           true = value, 
           false = NA_real_)
         ) |> 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(grp_id, season), 
              names_from = name, 
              values_from = value) |> 
  select(-grp_id) |> 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 4 × 7
  season level1_01 level1_02 level2_01 level2_02 level3_01 level3_02
  <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 level1        12        12        12        12        NA        NA
2 level1        10        10        10        10        NA        NA
3 level2         0         0         0         0        NA        NA
4 level2         3         3         3         3        NA        NA
```

Comment: I just realized my original didn't have the correct desired output. I have edited the original post.. Thank you for your help as your answer was useful for another portion of this project! Thanks this is great!

Comment: Ah, that makes the `str_detect` much simpler.  See updated answer!